# How to troubleshoot the Azure functions local debug error: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: provider

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

My Azure functions project has abruptly stopped working while local debugging with the following error:

> Building host: startup suppressed:False, configuration suppressed:
>   False Value cannot be null. Parameter name: provider

Any help with troubleshooting the issue will be appreciated. I can add more info to the post as required.

Comment: we can't help you unless you post code

Comment: Yes, please post relevant parts of your code. In this case at least the function definition including its bindings. Also which Function version v1 or v2

Comment: Thanks for your responses. The issue was auto resolved.

Comment: Can you leave a brief note about anything you may have done to resolve this issue? I'm experiencing the same issue and can't figure out how to resolve it.